# Circuit for flashing LEDs for airplane model wing, tail and beacon lights using 555

Tags: 555, astable

I am working to make flashing LEDs for my airplane model. There are three LED pulse sequences on the picture below where to flash LEDs respectively.

So how do I design a circuit using an astable multivibrator using the IC 555 timer?

How do I design resistor and capacitor values?

[image]

Comment: XY problem I'm afraid.

Comment: You really need to provide the full spec: http://utcaerospacesystems.com/cap/systems/Interiors%20Documents/Lighting%20Systems/06%20Anti-Collision%20Lights/06_0010%20LED%20Anti-Collision%20Lighting%20System%20A320.pdf

Comment: There, for example, it says that the red LED beacon light operates at "20 ms – 200 ms (20 ms when dimmed by Power Supply)" and this differs significantly from the "Flashing sequences and synchronization" chart, which appears to show 100 ms.

Comment: I dont think that the 555 timer would get FAA approval .The 555 timer is in www.badbeetles.com .There are other ways.

Comment: Andyaka's "XY problem" comment means that you are asking about one thing (Y) but want an answer to another (X). This implies that Andyaka thinks that there is a better way to make these than an electrical circuit. (Unfortunately the "X" question wouldn't be on-topic here.)

Answer (score 20):

The granularity of the light sequence suggests a 555 oscillator period of 0.1 seconds (10 Hz). From there, it is a matter of counting and decoding:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0WHEU.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: +1 Although I would certainly use a micro as Olin suggests, this is a nice answer. OP: If it's not obvious, you could use 3/4 of a quad NOR for the two gates shown, so two 14/16-pin and one 8-pin package.

Comment: I would use two diodes and a resistor for the OR, two gates of a 4093 for the AND, and one of the remaining gates for the oscillator to eliminate the dreaded 555. A microcontroller is only an easy solution if you've already climbed the learning curve. Although a PICAXE 08M would do the job without much learning.

Answer (score 17):

The obvious answer here is to not even try to do this with evil <s>666</s> 555 timers.  You want three signals that need to be kept in phase, and one of them is a double pulse.  While this could eventually be accomplished with a mess of 555 timers, it is actually quite simple to do in firmware.  All you need is a micro with 3 outputs.  Even the tiny PIC 10F200 can do this job.

It looks like everything happens on a 50 ms boundary.  Set up a 50 ms tick, then walk thru 20 consecutive states triggered by the tick.  This is very easy.  Or, you have a array with 20 entries of 3 bits each.  Each 50 ms tick, you advance the array index, wrapping from 19 back to 0, then output the three bits to the three output pins.